# Why's this postgres regexp_match giving me null instead of the regex groups?

Tags: regex, postgresql, regex-group, postgres-9.6

This:

```
select regexp_matches('test text user:testuser,anotheruser hashtag:peach,phone,milk site:youtube.com,twitter.com flair:bobby', '^.*?(?=\s+[^:\s]+:)|([^:\s]+):([^:\s]+)','gi');
```

gives me only one group match and a row with NULL:

```
regexp_matches  
-----------------
 {NULL,NULL}
 {flair,bobby}
```

It works fine when I test it here:

https://regex101.com/r/AxsatL/3

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you are doing wrong is assuming that all regular expression engines are the same. They are *NOT*.  Test and build your expression with the engine it's going to run on. In this case Postgres; See Postgres [Pattern Matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-matching.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
'^(?:(?!\s+[^:\s]+:).)*|[^:\s]+:[^:\s]+'
```

The point here is to keep all quantifiers greedy and remove all capturing parentheses.

The `^(?:(?!\s+[^:\s]+:).)*` part will match - from the start of the string - any char, 0 or more occurrences, that does not start a sequence of the following patterns: 1+ whitespaces, 1+ chars other than `:` and whitespace and then a `:`.

[Online test](https://rextester.com/WJKBT48612):

```
select regexp_matches(
    'test text user:testuser,anotheruser hashtag:peach,phone,milk site:youtube.com,twitter.com flair:bobby',
    '^(?:(?!\s+[^:\s]+:).)*|[^:\s]+:[^:\s]+',
    'gi'
);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: When I test it on a real postgres db, it gives me a bit different result: {"test text",NULL,NULL}
 {NULL,user,"testuser,anotheruser"}
 {NULL,hashtag,"peach,phone,milk"}
 {NULL,site,"youtube.com,twitter.com"}
 {NULL,flair,bobby}

Comment: @PranoyC Remove capturing parentheses.